# Number system question

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics

Is it true that if we are given a number system with base 3, mantissa 2, $-1 \le p \le 1$, determined by $$\pm 0.d_1 d_2 \times 3^p$$ where each number is normalized, unless it is zero, then the smallest positive number would be $0.10 \times 3^{-1}$, and the biggest would be $0.22 \times 3^1$? Just want to make sure I'm not mistaken in my understanding of the concept. Some feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Smallest in magnitude, not smallest in value.

Comment: Sorry, what is the difference between magnitude and value in this case?

Comment: The smallest value would be $-0.22\times3^1$

Comment: And $\pm 0.01\times 3^p$ would be the smallest non-zero values in magnitude.

Comment: @almagest, I apologize, I meant the smallest positive number.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius, can you please clarify the difference between magnitude and value?

Comment: @LaarsHelenius, so shouldn't the smallest in magnitude be $0.10 \times 3^{-1}$?

Comment: If you are using tertiary numbers, the first decimal place is $d_1\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ while the second place is for $d_2\left(\frac{1}{3^2}\right)$. So $0.01=\frac{1}{9}$ is definitely smaller than $0.1=\frac{1}{3}$. Think about normal decimals Which is closer to zero: 0.1 or 0.01?

Comment: RIght. I just wanted to make sure I didn't have confusions about this way of mantissa-base representations.

Answer (score 1):

Think of all the numbers arranged on a number line with numbers to the right of zero deemed positive and numbers to the left of zero as negative.

The value of a number is said to be where it appears on the number line. The number furthest to the right (if there is one) is the number with maximum value and the number furthest to the left (again, if there is one) is the number with minimum value. If every number has a value (it appears somewhere on our number line) then we can order them from smallest to largest.

The magnitude of a number is how far away it is from 0. The number(s) closest to zero have the smallest magnitude and the number(s) furthest away have the largest magnitude.

For example, on the real number line $-3$ has a smaller value than $2$ (it is to the left of $2$), but $-3$ has a greater magnitude that $2$ (as it is further from $0$ than $2$ is). Meanwhile $-1$ has a smaller value than $1$, but they have the same magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Basically, it's the absolute value (or modulus) of the number. I was a bit confused by terminology then.

Comment: Sorry if the answer was a bit pedantic. I really couldn't come up with a slicker way of thinking about it. Magnitude is most definitely best captured as an absolute value (or modulus).